# Different controllers for views on the same folder on asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, split, controllers

I've been researching about this. I found "MVCs areas" but I still couldn't do what I'm looking for.

MY VIEWS: 
Views/
 Student/Course
 Student/Information
 Student/Status
 Student/GeneralSituation
 etc, etc...

CONTROLLERS:

Controllers/Student

What I want to do is:

I don't want to have All the code from a lot of views in just one "Student" controller. 
Any tip regarding how I can "split" my controllers in several files?
I'm just looking at the simplest approach, I don't want to make big modifications to my project.

I'm using MVC4.

Thanks in advance!..

PnP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a partial class StudentController:

your folder/files would look like this:

```
Controllers
  StudentController
    StudentController.Status.cs
    StudentController.GeneralSituation.cs
    StudentController.Course.cs
```

The code would be:

**StudentController.Status.cs:**

```
public partial class StudentController
{
    [Actions relevant for Status of a student]
}
```

**StudentController.GeneralSituation.cs:**

```
public partial class StudentController
{
    [Actions relevant for General Situation of a student]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make partial Controller classes and thus split one controller over a bunch of physical files?

Also, what do you mean by "the code from a lot of views"? Are you using a separate service layer and doing the business logic in there, because that's best practice. Controllers are meant to be very lightweight with code along the lines of this:

```
public ActionMethod DoSomething()
{
    StudentViewModel vm = _studentService.GetSomeData();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why Area's don't work? From what you described, I don't really see why they wouldn't.

```
- Areas
    - Students
      - Controllers
          HomeController           Handles base /Students/ route
          InformationController    ~/Students/Information/{action}/{id} 
          StatusController         ~/Students/Status/{action}/{id}
          ...
      - Models
      - Views
          Home/
          Information/
          Status/
          ...
          Shared/        Stick common views in here
```

If you're set on one monster controller (or partials), your controller should have very little actual 'View code' in it. Leave all that to view models - the controller just passes in the needed resources to build view data, keeping controllers thin.

Ie,

```
public class StudentController
{
    ...

    // Actually I prefer to bind the id to a model and handle 404
    // checking there, vs pushing that boiler plate code further down 
    // into the controller, but this is just a quick example.

    public ActionResult Information(int id)
    {
        return View(new InformationPage(this.StudentService, id));
    }
}
```

Then, `InformationPage` is one of your models that will handle building out all information applicable to that view.

```
public class InformationPage
{
     public Student Student { get; set; }

     public InformationPage(StudentService service, int studentId)
     {
         Student = service.FindStudent(studentId);
         ... Other view data ...
     }
}
```